# import views.py from app directory

Tags: python, django

In setting up `Django` app, I want to import `main_app/views.py` in the `url.py`

of the `main project folder`. `main_app` folder is located parallel to the `main project folder`.

Here is how I am referencing to import `views.py` in `main project folder\url.py`:

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('../main_app')

from django.conf.urls import url 
from  django.contrib import admin
from  django.urls import path 
from  main_app import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', 'main_app.urls'), 
]
```

However, I am receiving `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_app'`

Comment: why do you use import sys? that's not the way to call django moules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still get the same error of `ModuleNotFoundError`, but the project url dispatcher is now able to call `main_app` url dispatcher and I am able to load webpage.

I have updated `settings.py` to include `main_app`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

and also updated `main_app\urls.py` and added `from . import views`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns= [
    url(r'^$',views.index),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it, it is useless

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('main_app.urls')),
]
```

This should be perfectly working

Answer (score 1):

If you used

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/#creating-the-polls-app

```
python manage.py startapp main_app
```

You should not have a problem with the code you posted since inside a project each app created is available automatically.

As per the documentation, it should look like this:

```
main_project/
    main_app/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
```

Then you add the app in settings.py:

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main_app.apps.FooConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

In case you created a custom folder, for whatever reason, for it to be accesible in the project, you have to add an `__init__.py` file at he root of the folder.

```
main_project/
    my_custom_lib/
        __init__.py
        my_custom_methods.py
```

Then if you want to call it

```
from my_custom_lib import my_custom_methods
```